# Tensorflow Federated - can't install

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-federated

i try to install **Tensorflow federated** but it won't install

by using `pip install --upgrade tensorflow-federated` in Command Prompt it start to download version 0.48.0
but it says its trying to find a compatible version and starts to download all version down to 0.17.0, then `error: subprocess-exited-with-error` will rise

i have python 3.10.11(no anaconda or similar app)

anybody knows what should i do?

[Command Prompt error picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4iEju.png)